# mod_rewrite hide .php extension and remove additional headers

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to hide php extension in url and in the responses of my Apache

I tried it with the following tipycal configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
...
```

but I do not understand why Apache adds a set of headers that I think are unnecessary.
for example about this url:

```
http://mysite/page
```

**Edit:**
disabling Content Negotiation with -MultiViews cause:

```
# tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sun Jan 19 16:35:23 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Jan 19 16:35:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3063): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /var/www/index.php
[Sun Jan 19 16:35:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/index.php
...
[Sun Jan 19 16:35:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/index.php
[Sun Jan 19 16:35:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /page
[Sun Jan 19 16:35:23 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 533 to 322 : URL /var/www/index.php


# tailf /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log 
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2014:18:42:06 +0100] [mysite/sid#7fa89ea62d58][rid#7fa89ed69340/initial] (1) pass through /page
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2014:18:42:06 +0100] [mysite/sid#7fa89ea62d58][rid#7fa89ed69340/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] internal redirect with /var/www/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2014:18:42:06 +0100] [mysite/sid#7fa89ea62d58][rid#7fa89ed75738/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /var/www/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2014:18:42:06 +0100] [mysite/sid#7fa89ea62d58][rid#7fa89ed75738/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/] internal redirect with /var/www/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jan/2014:18:42:06 +0100] [mysite/sid#7fa89ea62d58][rid#7fa89ed77ad0/initial/redir#2] (1) pass through /var/www/index.php
...
```

Comment: Such as:... it doesn't say anything

Comment: Hiding this info does not increase security. Bots have hardcoded sets of know vulnerabilities that are tried in a brute-force way, without consideration of your php version / file extension in URL.

Comment: for most would like to remove these headers to a question of performance
I want to have the smallest possible number of http header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
Options -Indexes -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You think that this is `mod_rewrite` that takes care of the renaming, but it is actually [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), more specifically the `Multiviews` Option, because apparently, `mod_negotiation` is executed earlier than `mod_rewrite` in the request lifecycle in Apache 2.0 and later.

What's happening is that when requesting `http://mysite/page` and a `page` file does not exists in the corresponding directory, mod_negotiation will try to locate files with the pattern `page.*`.
If a file named `page.php` is indeed present, mod_negotiation will then tell Apache to handle the current request as if `http://mysite/page.php` had been requested, and sets a few response headers, that are used mainly to help client-side caching:

```
Vary: negotiate
```

Content negotiation is being used for this request.

```
TCN: choice
```

This means the resource is transparently negotiated, choice means the 'best' variant has been returned, and the original name for the variant is present in the `Content-Location` header.

```
Content-Location: page.php
```

This is set in order for the browser to know that `page.php` is the best variant for `page`.

So the solution in your case is to disable content negotiation, either by ensuring that
 `Options -Multiviews`
is present, or by making sure `mod_negotiation` is not loaded at all, so you can be certain that `mod_rewrite` will handle the renaming instead, without adding those headers.

Comment: I have disabled the negotiation as you suggested me, but now I get 500 error and the apache log contains: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects..."

Comment: This new issue must be caused by mod_rewrite. Activate rewrite logging and you'll be able to more easily diagnose this.

Comment: In my last edit append then rewrite logs, the urls without .php not work!  it's very strange

Answer (score -1):

Try this code (But both php and non-php tagged will work with it, unless you make it redirect them)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewruteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php
```

For more information check this link - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

Comment: this does not change anything